# trying to implement a talks.js library to create chat on react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chat

I'm trying to implement a talks.js library to create chat on react
I follow all steps that show up here https://talkjs.com/docs/Getting_Started/Frameworks/React/ but it's not working, I don't know what I'm missing up

I'm exporting this component below and importing in home component

```
import { useRef } from 'react';
import Talk from 'talkjs';

const UserChat = () => {

const talkjsContainer = useRef('root');
// const currentUser = this.props.currentUser;
    useEffect(() => {
      Talk.ready.then(( ) => {

        var me = new Talk.User({
            id: '123456',
            name: 'Alberto',
            email: 'alice@example.com',
            photoUrl: 'https://demo.talkjs.com/img/alice.jpg',
            welcomeMessage: 'Hey there! How are you? :-)',
        });

        window.talkSession = new Talk.Session({
            appId: 'tUOOCMxO',
            me: me,
          });


          var other = new Talk.User({
            id: '654321',
            name: 'Sebastian',
            email: 'Sebastian@example.com',
            photoUrl: 'https://demo.talkjs.com/img/sebastian.jpg',
            welcomeMessage: 'Hey, how can I help?',
            role: 'default',
          });
        
          var conversation = window.talkSession.getOrCreateConversation(
            Talk.oneOnOneId(me, other)
          );
        
          conversation.setParticipant(me);
          conversation.setParticipant(other);

          var inbox = window.talkSession.createInbox();
          inbox.select(conversation);

       
          inbox.mount(talkjsContainer.current)

      });
    }, []);

    
        return(
            
            <div ref={talkjsContainer}></div>
        ) 
        
    

}

export default UserChat;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this

```
   const startChat = (user) => {
    if (!window.talkSession ) {
      return false;
    }
    const other = new Talk.User({
      id: "1222222",
      name: "james",
      email:"james1@yandex.com",
      role: buyer 
    });
    const conversation = 
    window.talkSession.getOrCreateConversation(Talk.oneOnOneId(me, other));
    conversation.setParticipant(me);
    conversation.setParticipant(other);

    const popup = window.talkSession.createPopup(conversation, { keepOpen: false });
    popup.mount({ show: false });

    popup.show();
  };
```

Comment: i try this code but is not working u mean too that I don't need de appId that talks provide as I sett on top of my comment  to be specific this part                                                                     window.talkSession = new Talk.Session({
            appId: 'tUOOCMxO',
            me: me,
          });    or maybe I'm setting it in a wrong way would be great to have more details on implemetantios and I hope not  bored you too much

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
for appId you need to add your appId and also you need to add role on your talkjs app .


   const startChat = () => {
    const container = React.createRef();

    Talk.ready.then(() => {
     const me = new Talk.User({
    id: "222",
   name: "jorge",
   email: "jorge23@yandex.com",
    role: "buyer",
     });
    window.talkSession = new Talk.Session({
      appId: "",
      me,
    });

   const other = new Talk.User({
      id: "122333333",
       name: "heelo",
       email: "test122@yopmail.com",
       role: "vendor",
     });

     inbox.show();
    });
  
  const me = new Talk.User({
   
    id: "2222",
    name: "hii",
    email: "test2@yopmail.com",
    welcomeMessage: "Hey there! How are you? :-)",
  });
  const other = new Talk.User({
    id: "122333333",
    name: "heelo",
    email: "test1@yopmail.com",
     role: "vendor",
  });
  useEffect(() => {
    Talk.ready.then(() => {
      if (!window.talkSession) {
        window.talkSession = new Talk.Session({
          appId: "",
          me,
        });
      }
      const conversation = window.talkSession.getOrCreateConversation(Talk.oneOnOneId(me, other));
      conversation.setParticipant(me);
      conversation.setParticipant(other);
      const inbox = window.talkSession.createInbox(conversation.current);
      inbox.mount(container.current);
    });
  });
   window.talkSession = new Talk.Session({
      appId: "",
     me,
    });
   if (!window.talkSession) {
      window.talkSession = new Talk.Session({
       appId: "",
       me,
     });
   }

    const conversation = window.talkSession.getOrCreateConversation(Talk.oneOnOneId(me, other));
    conversation.setParticipant(me);
   conversation.setParticipant(other);
   const inbox = window.talkSession.createInbox({ selected: conversation });
  const talkjsContainer = React.createRef();
const talkjsContainer = React.createRef();
    return <div ref={(e) => (container = e)} >
        loading.....
        </div>
  };
  return (
    <div style={{ height: "" }} ref={container}>
      loading.....
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: hi, I think your code is kind duplicate everywhere, I try it but still is not working I had to comment some parts of the code because was given me errors but again was pretty difficult to understand what part of the code should be added and what to be commented